# Android Alpha Internal Release Cannot Log In. Where can I check the log files?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, android-log

I've released my app in internal alpha on google play, received the URL, and installed the app on a phone via the URL link. There is a bug where users cannot log in. If the app is installed with android studio via USB link, the app works fine, even if I disconnect the USB from the PC running Android studio, the app works fine without the login issue. If the app is installed via the play store URL link, the bug occurs.

1.) What difference is there between Android Studio installing an app on a phone and Google Play (Internal Alpha) URL links installing an app on a phone? Specifically, what differences are there that would cause a login problem?

Because this bug doesn't happen when I use android studio to launch the app, I can't use Android Studio to view the logs while the app is running!

2.) What tools can I use to diagnose this problem on an independently running android device? (Galaxy S7 in this case). Perhaps there a way I can view the logs of the app on the phone? Or use Android Studio to view the debug of the running app without using Android Studio to install the app?

Comment: Have you generated signature apk for alpha release?

Comment: Yes. I've generated a signed APK via Android Studio >> Build >> Generate Signed APK. I selected "Jar Signature" and "Full APK signature" options. I've also enabled "Google Play App Signing" via the developer console. Could that have something to do with it? Perhaps I should try re-uploading a new signed APK or using Google Play to download a new keystore file if I did something out of order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was created when Google Play App Signing was enabled for my app. Google Play App Signing changes the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint (from what is in my keystore) to their own SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

**The fix:**

1. **Goto** https://play.google.com/apps/publish/
2. **Click** your application >> Release Management >> App Signing.

   You will see "App signing certificate" and  "Upload certificate"
3. **Copy** the SHA-1 From "**App Signing** Certificate." (**THE TOP ONE**)
4. **Goto** https://console.firebase.google.com/
5. **Click** your application >> Settings [Gearbox Icon to the right of
   project overview] (top of the screen) >> Project Settings >> General
   [Tab] >> Add Fingerprint
6. **Paste** the SHA-1 App Signing Certificate. Save.

All fixed!